# Calling a rest API from a yesod handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have yesod webserver ,with oauth implemented using the standard procedure in the yesodBook.
One of my POST handlers calls a rest api ,in a different webserver .
To rest using using postman . I made the following changes so that it works.
Commented out

```
-- yesodMiddleware :: ToTypedContent res => Handler res -> Handler res
-- yesodMiddleware = defaultYesodMiddleware
```

and

```
isAuthorized (postBanksR a) _ = return Authorized
```

the post requests me an error when I try to test it

```
Status: 303 See Other 0.000248996s
```

Basically it redirects to auth/google .
However if I use GET it works.

Comment: That's not an error. It just is a redirection. This is likely because your `GetBanksR a` will make changes to the db, and make a redirect (usually a succesful post should redirect), due to the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , I think worded the question wrong , I understand its redirecting , but instead of redirecting to the url (a rest api not google auth) I want it to go to , it goes to the authR handler , I want to disable this behaviour ,So i basically want to understand which piece of code in the scaffolded yesod website is actually responsible for this.

Comment: normally there should be a function named `postGetBanksR` that handles the request, and thus might/might not return the 303.

Comment: my postBankR is basically , Call a url , format the data returned by the url ,return the formatted data, in the call url step ,as soon as it tries to call the url ,it gets kicked into  GET auth/login , maybe becuase I dont have the authentication token  present in the session,  I want to stop yesod from doing that verification . I don't want it to verify whether the request is authenticated or not

Comment: if you set to `return Authorized`(and there is no clause above that one that matches), then Yesod will just allow it. Perhaps it is the URL you trigger that is authorizing?

Comment: from the docs "Yesod Middleware allows you to run code before and after each handler function " . can it be that the middle ware is trying to authenticate request "leaving" as it is the requests "coming in"

Comment: the `defaultYesodMiddleware` adds some headers and makes an `isAuthorized` check, the one you just have set to `return Authorized`, in that case it will leave it. If it was  (src: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.14/docs/src/Yesod.Core.Class.Yesod.html#defaultYesodMiddleware)

Comment: you can however just specify the `yesodMiddleware` as `yesodMiddleware = id`, to circumvent that.

Comment: it didn't solve it , my external call basically looks like r <- liftIO $ Wreq.post submitForSignUrl (toJSON Arguments)  , is there something wrong with the way I am calling it ?

Comment: well if I understand it correctly, you just return the result of that call. So it looks like you did not submit the credentials in the POST call your Yesod server made to a web service. You should consult the specs of the `submitForSignUrl` endpoint and see how you should add a usertoken/(other form of authentication)...

Comment: the submitfor Sign url doesnt expect any authentication , moreover I run into this problem only when I use POST request , so getBankR works with the same exact piece of code , but postBankR doesnt.

Comment: but do you make a POST request to the `submitForSignUrl` in your GET handler as well?

Comment: yes , I just copied the code from the POST to GET ,exact same code , only difference is , the GET i can test from my browser so it has the session , the POST I am testing through a client so there is no session there , Thats why I added the return Authorized so that session doesnt create an issue.

Comment: I even added a   isAuthorized (_) _           = return Authorized  ,it still redirects to auth/login

Comment: Please do not put your code, or question in the comments.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , I got the thing resolved, the posttosign method basically had a call to the function requireAuthPair , commenting that fixed it for me .I think it was redirecting to the authRoute since the authPair was not present in the session . I guess I should change that to maybeAuthpair

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: successful POST requests frequently return a 303 response when it is successful. Error codes are in the 400-599 range (with 400-499 for client errors, and 500-599 for server errors). Status codes in the 300-399 range are used to redirect to another endpoint.

> the post requests me an error when I try to test it
>
> ```
> Status: 303 See Other 0.000248996s
> ```

This is *not* an error. A POST with correct data will, usually, return a redirect. This is due to the [*Post/Redirect/Get* architectural pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

In case the request is valid, the POST request will likely make changes to the database. If you would not make a redirect, then refreshing the page on the browser would result in another POST request (some browsers will first warn the user about that). A second POST could result in creating a second record, making a second payment, ordering a second item, etc. This is usually not what a user wants.

This behavior is documented in [**RFC 2612** about the *HTTP 1.1* protocol [ietf.org]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.4):

> This method exists primarily to allow the **output of a POST-activated
> script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource**. The new
> URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested
> resource.

We find a similar result on [The *HTTP Response Codes* page on *REST API Tutorial* [restfulapi.net]](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/):

> **303 (See Other)**
>
> A **303 response indicates that a controller resource has finished its
> work**, but instead of sending a potentially unwanted response body,
> it sends the client the URI of a response resource. This can be the
> URI of a temporary status message, or the URI to some already
> existing, more permanent, resource.
>
> Generally speaking, the 303 status code **allows a REST API to send a
> reference to a resource without forcing the client to download its
> state**. Instead, the client may send a GET request to the value of
> the Location header.
>
> The 303 response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second
> (redirected) request might be cacheable.